# Rails - How to scope all routes in the app with user_ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, scope, uri

I'm looking to do what Basecamp does essentially, having my URIs be like this:

`www.example.com/:user_id/
www.example.com/:user_id/projects/12314`

Where you can only access that which is scoped under your user_id.

My ideas so far are:

1. To nest all other resources under `users`
2. To use a scope `scope: ":user_id" do`

And then just passing `current_user` whenever I create a path.

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best approach is  to implement nested routing(the one you are thinking of) to handle the above scenario, in which resources will be nested under parent. But you also need to think about the individual existence of resources whether they exists or not without user as sometimes few routes can exists without user so for that you also need to define them seperately in routes.rb.

as reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

as example:   http://blog.8thcolor.com/en/2011/08/nested-resources-with-independent-views-in-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with what you suggested.